# Did R. Buckminster Fuller reference a corollary of a mathematical theorem in his book _Critical Path_?

Tags: soft-question, differential-topology, mathematical-modeling, fixed-point-theorems

From *Critical Path* (1981) , Part 2, Chapter 6 "The World Game" , Richard Buckminster Fuller & Kiyoshi Kuromiya make the Claim :

> It has been found that within a 100 mile radius a wind is always blowing.

It is known that there exists *The Hairy Ball Theorem* which has as a corollary that at any given time on the Earth there is a cyclone happening somewhere. Was R. Buckminster Fuller aware of another mathematical theorem when he made this statement?

reference :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_Path_(book)#Chapter_6_-_World_Game
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem

Comment: As written, it's not a mathematical theorem: it is possible that the wind is blowing nowhere on earth.

Comment: Who knows what he was aware of ? Are you aware of the vector field that vanishes identically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting a longish comment here :

**(0) Putting all the following Points together (TLDR) , what Fuller said is [Empirical](https://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=empirical) & Physical & Meteorological , not Mathematical. There is not much of a Connection to the Hairy Ball Theorem.**

(1) [The Hairy Ball Theorem](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/maths-hairy-ball-theorem-has-surprising-implications/) applies to the Whole Sphere , not to 100-mile Patches.
[image: Hairy Ball]
There may be no Cyclone in the Purple Patch.
The left Pole & the Right Pole have Discontinuities.

(2) The Statement about Earthly Cyclones might be called Observation , not Theorem or Corollary.
Approximating the Earth with a Sphere is not very Exact , Mathematically.
Consider [Sea Arches](https://www.britannica.com/science/sea-arch) & [land Arches](http://worldlandforms.com/landforms/natural-arch/) :
[image: Sea Arch] [image: Land Arch]
It might look like topological handles on Sphere or torus , where the Hairy Ball Theorem is not Mathematically applicable & it is hence not valid.

(3) The Hairy Ball theorem is valid when every Point on the Sphere has Exactly 1 tangent vector.
The Wind on the Earth is not like that. It might flow in multiple [Speeds/Directions](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Average-wind-speeds-in-m-s-vs-altitude-in-km-On-an-average-wind-speeds-are-minimum-in_fig1_328173177) at [various altitudes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wind_gradient) at the very Same Point (latitude & longitude) on the Earth.
Eg , Wind might move very very slowly on ground level , while it might move moderately fast on tall tower tips & the hot air balloon over-head might experience fast winds , while the Aeroplane might encounter very high Speed Wind , all at the Exact Same Point on the Earth.

[image: wind altitude]

[Wind Direction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wind) might matter too , changing with [altitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wind_gradient#/media/File:FAA-8083-13_Fig_7-20.PNG).

[image: Direction] [image: WIND SPEED]

Such Considerations are out of scope of the Hairy Ball theorem & hence we can not apply that here.

(4) There is no connection to 100 miles in the Hairy Ball theorem , which is Scale-Independent. We are then left with the Statement that the wind is moving in a Patch of 100 mm radius , which is not true.

(5) Physically , Wind is the outcome of heating (by Sun & Moon) & rotation & revolution (of Earth) , hence it is true that there is wind movement throughout the Earth. That there is always wind is additionally ensured by Human Constructions & Activities , Sea-Land Borders , Polar Ice, Volcanoes , Lakes , Dust , ETC , not by Hairy Ball Theorem.

(6) Putting all these together , what Fuller said is Empirical & Physical & Meteorological , not Mathematical. There is not much of a Connection to the Hairy Ball Theorem.